# I have a time list I want to group by on another key value having start time and end time load and date

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

```
data = [{'01-02-2022': [{'hour': '00:00', 'load': 8.0},
                        {'hour': '01:00', 'load': 8.0},
                        {'hour': '02:00', 'load': 5.0},
                        {'hour': '03:00', 'load': 5.0},
                        {'hour': '20:00', 'load': 5.0}]},
        {'02-02-2022': [{'hour': '00:00', 'load': 46.0},
                        {'hour': '01:00', 'load': 0.0},
                        {'hour': '02:00', 'load': 5.0},
                        {'hour': '03:00', 'load': 5.0},
                        {'hour': '20:00', 'load': 5.0}]},
        {'03-02-2022': [{'hour': '00:00', 'load': 7.0},
                        {'hour': '01:00', 'load': 456.0},
                        {'hour': '02:00', 'load': 5.0},
                        {'hour': '03:00', 'load': 5.0},
                        {'hour': '20:00', 'load': 5.0}]},
        {'04-02-2022': [{'hour': '00:00', 'load': 56587.0},
                        {'hour': '01:00', 'load': 3.0},
                        {'hour': '02:00', 'load': 5.0},
                        {'hour': '03:00', 'load': 5.0},
                        {'hour': '20:00', 'load': 5.0}]},
        {'05-02-2022': [{'hour': '00:00', 'load': 6796.0},
                        {'hour': '01:00', 'load': 7.0},
                        {'hour': '02:00', 'load': 5.0},
                        {'hour': '03:00', 'load': 5.0},
                        {'hour': '20:00', 'load': 5.0}]},
        {'06-02-2022': [{'hour': '00:00', 'load': 6879.0},
                        {'hour': '01:00', 'load': 56.0},
                        {'hour': '02:00', 'load': 5.0},
                        {'hour': '03:00', 'load': 5.0},
                        {'hour': '20:00', 'load': 5.0}]},
        {'07-02-2022': [{'hour': '00:00', 'load': 89.0},
                        {'hour': '01:00', 'load': 789.0},
                        {'hour': '02:00', 'load': 5.0},
                        {'hour': '03:00', 'load': 5.0},
                        {'hour': '20:00', 'load': 5.0}]}]


day_hours = ['00:00','01:00','02:00','03:00','04:00','05:00','06:00','07:00','08:00',
             '09:00','10:00','11:00','12:00','13:00','14:00','15:00','16:00','17:00',
             '18:00','19:00','20:00','21:00','22:00','20:00']
```

I am new to Python and need the below output based on list grouping (if same load and sequence of the time array present for same date, If the load is same but hour sequence or same date is not matching we will not group them, instead that we will create new enter for like with `start_date`, `start_time`, `end_time`, and `load`). I tried with multiple combinations but due to I am new on this technology unable to write the right syntax and code. Could you please help me with the right code.

Below is the code which I have tired:

```
def day_hour(item):
    d,h = item['day'],item['hour']
    h,m = h.split(':')
    return (d,int(h),int(m))

# sort by day and hour
data.sort(key=day_hour)
# group by day and load
grouped_data = groupby(data, operator.itemgetter('day','load'))
i = 0
result =[]
first_iteration = True
while True:
    try:
        i += 1
        (day,load), grp = next(grouped_data)
        grp = list(grp)
        first = grp[0]
        last = grp[-1]
        if first_iteration:
            previous = {'start_date':day, 'start_time':first['hour'], 'end_time':None, 'peak_load':load}
            first_iteration = False
        else:
            if 'prev_last' in locals():
                if prev_last['hour'] != "23:00":
                    hour_index = day_hours.index(prev_last['hour'])
                    end = day_hours[hour_index + 1]
                else:
                    end = "24:00"
            else:
                if "prev_last" not in locals():
                    if last['hour'] != "23:00":
                        hour_index = day_hours.index(last['hour'])
                        end = day_hours[hour_index]
                    else:
                        end = "24:00"
            previous['end_time'] = end
            result.append(previous)
            previous = {'start_date':day, 'start_time':first['hour'], 'end_time':None, 'peak_load':load}
            prev_last = last
    except StopIteration as e:
        if "prev_last" in locals():
            if prev_last['hour'] != "23:00":
                hour_index = day_hours.index(prev_last['hour'])
                end = day_hours[hour_index]
            else:
                end = "24:00"
        previous['end_time'] = end
        result.append(previous)
        break
```

While running my code it is giving me the output but it is not correct. If there is gape between the time of same date but loads are same. Its end_time is taking as gaped hour value.

Suppose for 01-02-2022 : `[[{'hour': '00:00', 'load': 8.0}, {'hour': '05:00', 'load': 8.0}]`,
it is giving me below wrong result:

```
[{'start_date':'01-02-2022','start_time': '00:00', 'end_time': '06:00','peak_load': 8.0}]
```

expected result:

```
[{'start_date':'01-02-2022','start_time': '00:00', 'end_time': '01:00','peak_load': 8.0},
 {'start_date':'01-02-2022','start_time': '06:00', 'end_time': '07:00','peak_load': 8.0}
]
```

I am also getting issue when its last hour(23:00)
if there is any value for '23:00'. It should be like,

```
{'start_date': 01-02-2022, start_time:'23:00' end_time:'24:00', 'peak_load': 10}
```

---

Another Code which I have tried:

```
final_records = []
for d in data:
    key, values = next(iter(d.items()))
    first_iter = True
    dict = {}
    for value in values:
            dict["start_date"] = key
            if first_iter:
                    dict["start_time"] = value["hour"]
                    dict["load"] = value["load"]
                    prev_last_time = hours[hours.index(value["hour"]) + 1]
                    prev_start_time = value["hour"]
                    dict["end_time"] = prev_last_time
                    first_iter = False
                    # final_records.append(dict)
            else:

                    if value['load'] == dict["load"] and value["hour"] == prev_last_time:
                            prev_last_time = hours[hours.index(value["hour"]) + 1]
                            dict['end_time'] == prev_last_time
                            # final_records.append(dict)
                    else:
                            # final_records.append(dict)
                            dict["load"] = value['load']
                            dict['start_time'] = value['hour']
                            prev_last_time = hours[hours.index(value["hour"]) + 1]
                            dict['end_time'] = prev_last_time
                            final_records.append(dict)
```

required output format:

```
[{'start_date': '01-02-2022',
  'start_time': '00:00',
  'end_time': '01:00',
  'peak_load': 8.0},
 {'start_date': '01-02-2022',
  'start_time': '01:00',
  'end_time': '02:00',
  'peak_load': 56.0},
 {'start_date': '01-02-2022',
  'start_time': '02:00',
  'end_time': '04:00',
  'peak_load': 5.0},
 {'start_date': '01-02-2022',
  'start_time': '04:00',
  'end_time': '05:00',
  'peak_load': 40.0},
 {'start_date': '01-02-2022',
  'start_time': '06:00',
  'end_time': '07:00',
  'peak_load': 8.0},
 {'start_date': '01-02-2022',
  'start_time': '23:00',
  'end_time': '24:00',
  'peak_load': 89709.0},
 {'start_date': '02-02-2022',
  'start_time': '00:00',
  'end_time': '01:00',
  'peak_load': 46.0}]
```

Comment: Do not post screenshots of code, copy and paste it as text.

Comment: pasted the code.

Comment: Hi. Could you please rephrase the problem? I have a hard time understanding what you want to do. In particular, this sentence is a bit obscure to me: *"I am new to Python and need the below output based on list grouping (if same load and sequence of the time array present for same date, If the load is same but hour sequence or same date is not matching we will not group them, instead that we will create new enter for like with start_date, start_time, end_time and load). "*

Comment: I wanted the below output based on data provided (if same load and sequence of the hour array present for same date create one row with that day as start_date, start_time and end_time, If the load is same but hour sequence or same date is not matching we will not group them, instead that we will create new enter for like with start_date, start_time, end_time and load). end_time will be the next hour of start_time. and if load value and date are same and hour values are in sequence the start time will be hour of first list of dictionary and end time will be next hour of its date value data.

Comment: @Sassy, what is the purpose of `day_hours` list in your code? What logic does it follow? Your desired output looks absolutely random for me. That's why it's more common to post **minimal** reproducible example rather then entire code.

Comment: Hi @OlvinRoght, I am using day_hours list to get the index of current hour and its next hour which I am using while assigning end time and verifying if load value starrt time and end time are in a sequence. May I am doing some unnecessary steps here, as I am new to python. neep help to get the correct output.